# List project dependencies, sorted by date of release (to identify outdated dependencies)

Tags: maven, gradle, continuous-integration, dependencies, dependency-management

In Maven or Gradle, how can I fetch the release date for all dependencies, and then sort from oldest to newest?

I want to identify dependencies like Awaitility, which was moved from [com.jayway.awaitility:awaitility](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.jayway.awaitility/awaitility) (last updated 2015) to [org.awaitility:awaitility](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.awaitility/awaitility) (last updated 2020).

In this instance, checking for newer versions isn't enough. Sonatype reports "No vulnerabilities detected" https://ossindex.sonatype.org/component/pkg:maven/com.jayway.awaitility/awaitility

Vulnerability scanning might work, but it's not reliable or consistent, especially for the smaller, older, abandoned dependencies in which I am interested. It also doesn't work for company-internal dependencies.

Comment: While not designed for your exact use case this tool https://owasp.org/www-project-dependency-check/ can scan your dependencies for CVEs and may also help identify ones that have moved.

Comment: How will you be able to identify that dependency was moved into another group? Do you really need this functionality for sorting dependencies by dates? Wouldn't this plugin be enough to show you outdated dependencies? https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin

Comment: Both good options, I'm not discounting them, but I'm asking something different. Checking for newer versions doesn't detect abandoned/moved deps. Finding replacements can be done manually, after detection. Existing dependency-version & vulnerability checking tools don't catch the outdated dependencies I've found, and they don't work for private dependencies.